# Is to possible to prevent certain followers from seeing a tweet? (Twitter API)

Tags: twitter

Rather than removing followers, I would like to be able to be selective about which followers see a given tweet, is this possible? Does the Twitter API allow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Twitter API is a reflection of what Twitter can do in day to day use. You can not change the sharing settings of Tweets as you do in Facebook or Google+.

Answer (score 0):

A tweep can warn people by telling them that he or she sends *sensible* tweets. But there is not any Twitter API method for this. The user has to do this on the user settings of the Twitter website.